# $geoNear query not returning all records

Tags: node.js, mongodb, geolocation

I have a query that uses aggregation pipeline to retrieve all the records within a 200 mile radius. However, the query only returns 100 out of 156 records. I am not sure what the issue is. I have included the query in this thread. Greatly appreciate any feedback and help.

```
 pRadius = ((pRadius * Math.PI) / 180)*3963.2*69;

    return new Promise(function(fullfill, reject){

        Offers.aggregate(
            [
                { 
                    $geoNear: { 
                        near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [parseFloat(pLatLngArray[0]), parseFloat(pLatLngArray[1])] }, 
                        distanceField: "dist",
                        spherical: true, 
                        maxDistance: parseFloat(pRadius),
                        query: { 
                            $and: 
                                [ 
                                    { type_id: {$in: pTypeIDArray } }, 
                                    { valid: true } , 
                                    { $or: [ { enddate: null }, { enddate: { $gte: new Date() } } ] } 
                                ]
                        },
                    } 
                },
                {
                    $project : {
                        provider_id : 1
                        , providername: 1
                        , offer_id: 1
                        , title: 1
                        , description: 1
                        , additionalinfo: 1
                        , likecount: 1
                        , restrictions: 1
                        , imagepath: 1
                        , price: 1
                        , startdate: 1
                        , enddate: 1
                        , showrating: 1
                        , dist: 1
                        , logopath: 1
                        , _id: 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    $skip: Number(pStartIndex)
                },
                { 
                    $limit: Number(pEndIndex)
                },
            ]).exec().then(function(result){
                fullfill(result);
            }).catch(function(err){
                reject(err);
            });
    });
```

The document has the following indexes defined:

```
db.offers.getIndexes()
[
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "name" : "_id_",
    "ns" : "medmart_db.offers"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "loc" : "2dsphere"
    },
    "name" : "loc_2dsphere",
    "ns" : "medmart_db.offers",
    "background" : true,
    "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 2
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "loc" : "2d"
    },
    "name" : "loc_2d",
    "ns" : "medmart_db.offers",
    "background" : true
}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

So the fix is to set a higher return limit to aggregation pipeline.

```
return new Promise(function(fullfill, reject){

    Offers.aggregate(
        [
            { 
                $geoNear: { 
                    near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [parseFloat(pLatLngArray[0]), parseFloat(pLatLngArray[1])] }, 
                    distanceField: "dist",
                    spherical: true, 
                    maxDistance: parseFloat(pRadius),
                    limit: 999999, // set the limit here
                    query: { 
                        $and: 
                            [ 
                                { type_id: {$in: pTypeIDArray } }, 
                                { valid: true } , 
                                { $or: [ { enddate: null }, { enddate: { $gte: new Date() } } ] } 
                            ]
                    },
                } 
            },
            {
                $project : {
```

**Thanks to JP for his help finding the solution.**